# is pwrite after dup race safe?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, file

On Linux pwrite operation (which is seek+write) is atomic, meaning doing pwrite-s in multiple threads with one file descriptor is safe.
I want to create file descriptor duplicate, using dup(). Now, having fd1 and fd2 - will pwrite-s work as expected, or there's danger of race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pwrite is an atomic operation *if* the number of bytes you're writing is less than PIPE_BUF of the pipe you're writing to (from the [POSIX programmer's manual](http://unistd.info/man/pwrite)).

Comment: Thanks, but let's assume it is atomic, then do we have a problem?

Comment: If it is atomic then I think by definition you do not have a problem. Atomic means the pwrite operation will be performed in one go without being interrupted by other threads.

Comment: `pwrite` has nothing to do with pipes, and it's nonsensical to use it with pipes. `pwrite` is only meaningful for seekable files.

Answer (score 5):

File descriptor pairs created through `dup` share the same file status, (e.g. an `lseek` operation on one file descriptor will affect the other), because they refer to the *same* entry in the process open files table, which means they are essentially indistinguishable.  The only thing they do not have in common is file descriptor flags, (e.g. FD_CLOEXEC.)

From the man page:

> After a successful return from dup()
>   or dup2(), the old and new file
>   descriptors may be used
>   interchangeably. They refer to the
>   same open file description (see
>   open(2)) and thus share file offset
>   and file status flags; for example, if
>   the file offset is modified by using
>   lseek(2) on one of the descriptors,
>   the offset is also changed for the
>   other.

Given that `dup` allows you to use the two file descriptors *interchangeably*, (because they refer to the same file in the process file table) I assume this implies that calling `pwrite` on one would be the same as calling it on the other, and thus be atomic.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the answer. If there are 2 pwrites in 2 threads on duplicate file descriptors to different places in the file - is it OK?

Comment: Yes, it would be safe.  It *wouldn't* be safe if you opened the same file with `open`.  But if you use `dup` then the two file descriptors are basically indistinguishable, because they refer to the same entry in the process file table.

Comment: By safe i mean seek of fd1 will not interfere with seek of fd2, do u mean the same?